# Timer starts when computer is inactive

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

What code should I write to achieve this: IDLE Timer that will start after 15 minutes of no movement in the computer and the IDLE timer will stop if you do movement in the computer again.

Additionally, I want a timer (Activity timer) to stop when the IDLE timer starts. Then the Activity timer resumes when there is movement in the pc again and the IDLE timer stops.

This is what I have done so far:

```cs
namespace TITOMS_LOGIN
{
    public partial class Form3Admin: Form
    {
        int seconds;
        int minutes;
        int hours;
        public Form3Admin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            seconds = minutes = hours = 0;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form2Admin sw = new Form2Admin();
            sw.Show();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form5 se = new Form5();
            se.Show();
        }

        private void Form3Admin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
            Day.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            seconds++;

            if (seconds > 59)
            {
                minutes++;
                seconds = 0;
            }

            if (minutes > 58)
            {

                hours++;
                minutes = 0;

            }

            lblhours.Text = hours.ToString() + "HRS";
            lblminutes.Text = minutes.ToString() + "MINS";
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So is your question how to determine how long the user has been inactive for?

Comment: I have done some correction to the post. technically I need some help with the codes to achieve the given details. TIA

Comment: You want to subscribe a "mouse" moved event and start a 15 min countdown each time it is triggered, after that countdown, start counting the idle time (TimeSpan is your friend). You then add the countdown timers for the idle-time-count together for the active time or do some fancy smart algorithm. This may fit your expactation

Comment: Does the user interacting with a different application count as the user being active?

Comment: In addition to monitoring mouse movement, you'll also want to monitor whether any keystrokes have been pressed. You'll want to use a Win32 API such as mouse_move (example in c++ but the API name is the same: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove), etc.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes as long as there is movement in the computer it is count as being active.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan idleTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5);
            TimeSpan aa = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);


            if (UserInput.IdleTime >= idleTime && timer1.Enabled)
            {
                timer2.Start();
                timer1.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Stopped Timer 1, Start Timer 2 ");

            }
            else if (UserInput.IdleTime < aa && timer2.Enabled)
            {
                timer1.Start();
                timer2.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Stopped Timer 2, Start Timer 1 ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Idle for " + UserInput.IdleTime.ToString());

        }
```